# How to change /usr/bin/env?

Tags: ruby

I have scripts that use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` but I've switched to using Ruby Enterprise Edition instead of the default ruby that is included with Ubuntu server. Thus, the scripts freak out when I try to run them. How can I add the Ruby EE path to `/usr/bin/env`?

Answer (score 8):

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby` is similar to simply calling `ruby` from the command line, so the same rules apply. Basically, the individual entries in the `$PATH` environment variable are checked in order, and the `ruby` that is found first is used. So make sure that the `ruby` for Ruby EE is earlier in the search path order than your other `ruby`s.

I'm not familiar with Ruby EE, so if it doesn't have an executable called `ruby`, just create a symlink in a directory that's early in your search path to Ruby EE's executable.

Comment: could you explain how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Since you have an explicit dependency on Ruby EE, you could always modify the scripts instead of your environment ( which could have other unintended consequences ).

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

becomes

```
 #!/path/to/enterprise/edition/ruby
```

Now it becomes clear to the reader that you using a specific version of ruby rather than just whatever ruby is in your path.

Comment: This is fine as long as you're willing to completely give up on script portability.  In some cases that might not be such a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where cron jobs stopped working... Cron seems to run commands by default without using the PATH settings you would expect for the user (when logging in as that user). In fact it didn't even seem to use any of the default PATH settings (be it in /etc/profile or elsewhere).

I was able to find the problem using the following commands (the first one is how cron seems to run commands):

> su -c 'printenv PATH' userX

With output: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games

> su -l userX -c 'printenv PATH'

With output: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/:/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games

The first command doesn't seem to populate the PATH variable in any way except for the bare system default.
In my case I solved it by just adding the necessary (REE) path to: /etc/login.defs, which by default looks as follows:

/etc/login.defs:103:ENV_PATH    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games

Answer (score 1):

See section 1.6 in the Ruby EE documentation page:
http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html

For a system wide change you can update your PATH in the /etc/environment file to include the Ruby EE bin directory. Maybe something like this:

PATH="/opt/ruby-enterprise-x.x.x/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"

If you only want to the change to be visible for one user on the system you can update your .bashrc or .profile with the correct path.

Make sure to include the REE path first in the list of directories.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the solution I used on Ubuntu here:
http://groups.google.com/group/emm-ruby/browse_thread/thread/d0c685bbd096823a#msg_effa7d6ad42c541c

There were some additional steps to get it working beyond what was described in the Ruby Enterprise Edition documentation.