# Rails Paperclip Processor: shell command failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, ubuntu, paperclip

I've got a problem with a custom paperclip processor within my rails app. I upload a soundfile and the processor creates an waveform image via a shell command (provided by this [gem](https://github.com/benalavi/waveform))

I'm running RoR 3.2.7 / Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 (production environment). My model with paperclip attachment looks like the following:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :original_file,
                    :styles => { :waveform_image => { :waveform => true } },
                    :processors => [:sound_processor],
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
                    :url  => ":s3_eu_url",
                    :path => "sounds/:id/:five_digit_id_:basename_:style.:extension"
end
```

The corresponding Paperclip Processor:

```
class Paperclip::SoundProcessor < Paperclip::Processor

  def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
    # cut for brevity
  end

  def make
    src = @file
    dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @current_format])
    dst.binmode

    if @waveform
      cmd = "waveform #{File.expand_path(src.path)} #{File.expand_path(dst.path)}"
      Paperclip.log(cmd)
      out = `#{cmd}`
      dst = File.open "#{File.expand_path(dst.path)}"
    end

    dst
  end
end
```

When the command

```
waveform #{File.expand_path(src.path)} #{File.expand_path(dst.path)}
```

is getting executed on the production machine (Ubuntu 12.04), the following error comes up:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

However the usr/bin/env is a file instead of an directory. Since there is no ruby executable, how can I pass the right location when executing the shell command?

PS: On my development machine (OSX), on usr/bin/env is a copy of my rails app directory. It's working like a charm in development. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating that the ruby executable was not found. It is not related to the code that you have included in the question as of now.

The error is coming from the script file that includes the `waveform #{File.expand_path(src.path)} #{File.expand_path(dst.path)}` line.

Check out these answers to the issue: 
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6126419/429758
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241638/429758
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241593/429758
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064319/429758

They should give you some idea as to why the ruby executable is not being found on your production environment.